# When koshering meat by roasting can I put pepper

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, kashering-kosherization

What are the Ashkenazi and sifardi customs when kashering meat by roasting 
if it is permitted to use salt and/or other spices?

Answer (score 2):

Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah 76:2 - Translation from [sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.76.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> If one wishes to salt the meat before roasting it (2) [6] and eat it
>   without  washing it, one may do so and we are not worried about the
>   blood  remaining on the salt. Some say this ruling refers to one who
>   salted it, and  then immediately roasted it, (3) but if it lay in the
>   salt (4) the salt absorbs  and is forbidden. [7] Therefore it should
>   be well washed before the  roasting. Rema: [8] Some say that roasting
>   requires a preliminary washing  (Ramban), and some say that it
>   requires a slight salting beforehand as well  (Rashi). The custom is
>   to wash it first and then to lightly salt it when it is on  the
>   skewer, and to then immediately roast it so that the salt will not
>   absorb  blood. [9] Nevertheless, if it wasn’t washed or salted at all,
>   or it was salted  without having been washed first, and then roasted,
>   it is still permitted.  This is only if it did not sit idle in the
>   salt (5) without being washed for the  entire salting period, but if
>   it did indeed lay idle for this amount of time  before being roasted,
>   it is forbidden.

As you can see, there are divergent opinions. I am thus inferring what the purpose of the salt is, which seems to be for koshering and not for flavoring. Thus, if you follow the opinion that it does not need to be salted before roasting, then your adding salt is for flavoring, and it seems that you can add pepper or anything else you like. However, if you follow the opinion that the meat must be salted before roasting, then, it seems the meat is unkosher otherwise, beforehand, and the salt is for koshering purposes. Thus, adding pepper before koshering would make the pepper unkosher.

Comment: But the salt does not become not kosher even if it is used for kashering?

Comment: @hazoriz - Good question, and IIRC< based on what I saw in another par. in YD nearby, no, it doesn't happen. This is prob. why the par. above says that you have to roast it immediately after salting. I guess there is a time factor after which the salt is absorbed and is considered unkosher. I apologize that the version of YD I have now does not have commentaries, as I'm quite sure someone addresses this question, there.